# I am getting decimal number in place of whole number

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am getting decimal number on the y-axis of a bar chart as (0.0, 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0 and so on).

[image]

this is set a mask for the value axis labels.

```
<axisFormat tickLabelMask="0.0" verticalTickLabels="false">
                        <labelFont/>
                        <tickLabelFont/>
                    </axisFormat>
```

I want whole number in place of that (1,2,3,... and so on). How is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its very simple

In the IReport select your bar chart and click properties then go to Properties Expressions.
click add button and paste

```
net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval
```

as "Property Name" and and set 1 as "Value". (see image below)

hope this could help.

[image]